# Class not found error while creating Derby Context Aware Function with ClientDataSource driver

Tags: java, derby, javadb

I am using derby as datasource in weblogic with `org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDataSource` driver. I have started derby database with `${WL_HOME}/common/derby/bin/startNetworkServer.sh`

Datasource is getting created properly but while fetching connection and creating context aware function it throws class not found error.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: The class 'test.vti.VTITest' does not exist or is inaccessible. This can happen if the class is not public.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:530)
    at oracle.essbase.ds.manager.DataSourceManager.createDSView(DataSourceManager.java:340)
    at oracle.essbase.ds.manager.DataSourceManager.save(DataSourceManager.java:128)
    at test.DSDBTestWS.createDBDS(DSDBTestWS.java:290)
    at test.DSDBTestWS.saveDS(DSDBTestWS.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
```

How to include `test.vti.VTITest` in classpath so that `ClientDataSource` driver can find it?

Comment: test.vti.VTITest is already public class

Comment: If this is a class you wrote on your own, and want to make available in your Derby Network Server, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30734839/derby-java-trouble-with-create-type-statement/30738914#30738914